# JS find one element by class if exist else use other using the or operator

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm pure beginner in `JS`, I have a register modal in which after clicking on eye icon user gets typed password. Because of a lot of styling I can't used defined `eye` class that's why I want to add another one only for handled this event.

What I want to achieved is something like `eye.closest(":has(div)").find('.vr-textfield' || '.modal_eye')` but it seems like the `||` operator doesn't worked because nothing happened - no errors and password not showed up. Is this syntax is correct?

Whole method below:

```
// For Password field, display typed password on eye click
eyeIcon.click(function(evt) {
      var eye = $(this),
          field = eye.closest(":has(div)").find('.vr-textfield' || '.modal_eye'),
          isInTextMode = field.attr('type') == 'text';
      // update field and icon view
      if (!isInTextMode) {
        field.attr('type', 'text');
        eye.attr('src', eyeIconSrc.active);
      }
      else {
        field.attr('type', 'password');
        eye.attr('src', eyeIconSrc.inactive);
      }
    });
}
```

**view.html.erb**

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
  <%= f.password_field :password, class: "modal-new--registration-field vr-textfield with_icon", required: true, aria_required: true, pattern: ".{8,}" %>
  <%= image_tag "icon_eye.svg", class: "vr-textfield__icon modal_eye modal-new--registration-field-eye", alt: "Reveal password" %>
  <span class="modal-new--registration-field--invalid-msg">
    <%= t("attributes.password_requirements") %></span>
</div>
```

**Edit**

Ok I saw a lot of answer but can I implement the same logic for variable to achieve something like this? `var eyeIcon = $('.vr-textfield__icon && .eye || .modal_eye');`

Comment: `.find('.vr-textfield' || '.modal_eye'),` it will not works, you need to find like:
`field = eye.closest(":has(div)").find('.vr-textfield'),` `field2 = eye.closest(":has(div)").find('.modal_eye'),`

Comment: `.find(".vr-textfield, .modal_eye")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use or operator `||`, it will return the second operator only if the first operator is a *falsy* value. In your case, `'.vr-textfield'` is always a *truthy* value so your code never reaches `'.modal_eye'`. So, in your case you have to use `find()` using [`multiple selector`](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/):

```
eye.closest(":has(div)").find('.vr-textfield, .modal_eye')
```

Comment: [jQuery.find](https://api.jquery.com/find/) always returns a `jQuery` collection.

Comment: @Titus Wow, sorry about that, changed to `multiple selector` approach

Comment: I think this will do what the OP wants but you should probably mention that multiple selectors are not equivalent to using the OR operator.

Comment: @guijob thanks a lot! what if I want to achieve something similar but with defined variable? `var eyeIcon = $('.vr-textfield__icon && .eye || modal_eye ');` ?

Comment: @mr_muscle if you `var eyeIcon = $('.vr-textfield__icon.eye, .modal_eye ');` you will get in `eyeIcon` all elements who has both classes `vr-textfield__icon` *and* `eye`, and all elements who match `modal_eye`. your `&&` is made just writing two classes with no spaces: `.vr-textfield__icon.eye`.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `or` logical operators it will pass the first truthy value or if no truthy values are found, the final value is given.

Like:

```
"a" || "b" //"a"

"" || "b" //"b"

"" || "" //""

"" || undefined  //undefined

"" || [] // []
```

Comment: Add to your statement: "or if no truthy values are found, the final value is given".

Answer (score 0):

```
field = eye.closest(":has(div)").find('.vr-textfield' || '.modal_eye')
```

will not work, since the OR operator refers to the two string '.vr-textfield' and '.modal_eye'. And since '.vr-textfield' evaluates to true it is always selected.
You need to OR the two DOMElements:

```
var field1 = eye.closest(":has(div)").find('.vr-textfield');
var field2 = eye.closest(":has(div)").find('.modal_eye');

var field = field1.length ? field1 : field2;
```

It checks wether `field1` has any elements and if thats the case assign it to `field`, otherwise use `field2`